# OpenCV2 error: OpenCV(4.5.5) error: (-215:Assertion failed) img.channels() == 3 in function 'cv::tracking::impl::TrackerKCFImpl::getSubWindow'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm getting the following error when I'm running the proceeding codes below:

```
  File "C:\Users\angjw\Dropbox\NUS\Blink detection\mov files\Leye blink info extractor_v2.py", line 368, in <module>
    ret, bbox = tracker.update(roi)

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\tracking\src\trackerKCF.cpp:688: error: (-215:Assertion failed) img.channels() == 3 in function 'cv::tracking::impl::TrackerKCFImpl::getSubWindow'
```

The thing is, the same block of codes worked perfectly fine with cv2 version 4.0. And I can't quite figure out what has changed since that is causing cv2 to not be able to read img.channels() correctly. Does anyone have any idea? Note that I have cut short my original codes by a lot. But essentially, this block here reads a video clip and analyses designated range of video frames, frame by frame.

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
while True and frameCount <= COUNTlastframe:
    
    # Read a new frame
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        break   
    
    roi = frame[roiCoor1: roiCoor2, roiCoor3: roiCoor4]
    ## Do a drift correction every 600 frames (10s) (was 500; 8.33s)
    if frameCount % 600 == 0 and blinkStarted == False or frameCount == COUNTfirstframe:
        
        xylocalizer = [0,0,0,0]
        roi = frame[roiCoor1: roiCoor2, roiCoor3: roiCoor4]
        rows, cols, _ = roi.shape
        roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi, (7, 7), 0)
        
        _, threshold = cv2.threshold(roi, binaryThreshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) #min and max colour values for pupil threshold
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)   
            
        for cnt in contours:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            
            #cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            #cv2.line(roi, (x + int(w/2), y), (x + int(w/2), y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            break    
        
        ## Sum up the xy location of eye for the first xysample seconds.
        ## *1.25 arbitrary value to increase ROI box size for greater detection accuracy. 
        xylocalizer[0] = xylocalizer[0] + x    #x (from left)
        xylocalizer[1] = xylocalizer[1] + y    #y (from top)
        xylocalizer[2] = xylocalizer[2] + w*1.25    #box width
        xylocalizer[3] = xylocalizer[3] + h*1.25    #box height        
        
        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        ok = tracker.init(frame, (int(xylocalizer[0]),int(xylocalizer[1]),int(xylocalizer[2]),int(xylocalizer[3]))) 
        ret, bbox = tracker.update(roi)
```

Comment: i do not think, your code **ever** worked properly. you should not recreate the tracker or call init() in a loop, should not call update with a roi and not with a grayscale image

Comment: Hi there, thanks for assisting. These codes actually work when I run it with openCV version 4.0. And for a specific purpose of this analysis I am running, I need to run init() within a loop. In short, it has to do with the object that the KCF tracker tracks, tend to drift over time when the target of interest is immobile for an extended period of time. And the only way to fix this, is to reset the tracker constantly to re-center the fixation to the object of interest. In any case, the line that is driving the error is ret, bbox = tracker.update(roi) specifically.

Comment: Also unfortunately for the purpose of the current analysis, I need to have the image in grayscale.

Comment: iirc, you *can* use grayscale images, but you have to be consistant with init() & update(). however, `CF` in KCF are for Color Features, and you'll degrade performance. also, the image size for init() & update() must be the same. again, the problem is not changed opencv versions, but changes / errors in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little more digging and it seems that (-215:Assertion failed) img.channels() == 3 meant that the more recent tracker.update function using KCF requires the image to have 3 channels (ie. in colours). Because I had to convert my image to greyscale, this made my roi image into 1 channel.

To fix this, I just needed to add the following line before tracker.update to re-convert the greyscale image back into a colour image, after I was done with whatever I needed to do in greyscale:

```
roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Comment: the smarter thing would be to take the ROI from the original color image. then you don't have to spend work converting.

Comment: Right. The reason why I needed to convert to greyscale was because the roi image is essentially the pupil of our eyes. I'm building an eyeblink detection script that requires image to be black and white, where the blacks of the pupil that pass a certain threshold will be detected as the pupil. A blink happens when this 'blackness' disappears. This process is a lot noisier with a coloured image, hence the need for conversion. So I am not quite sure how else I can get this done without doing this conversion of image back and forth.